# How to add default values to React-Image-Annotate

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How can i populate React-Image-Annotate with values from apis, i want to add default poligon and points on page load, But i cant find any props for to give values to React-Image-Annotate.

here is a sample code

```
 <ReactImageAnnotate
  taskDescription="# Draw region around each animal."
  images={[
    {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561518776-e76a5e48f731?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80",
      name: "car-image-1"
    }
  ]}
  regionClsList={["car", "truck"]}
  enabledTools={["select", "create-polygon", "create-point"]}
  onExit={(event, value, value2) => console.log(event, value, value2)}
  
/>
```

here is a working sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-hodgkin-lt3org?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please read https://bestofreactjs.com/repo/bennylin77-react-annotation-tool-react-image-manipulation

Comment: that package doesnt have lot documentation,